# Package redis.embedded does not exist

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, redis

I work with a small `Spring Boot` project and I get the following error while using command `mvn clean install`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for SpringChatApp:com.messanger.chat:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar -> duplicate declaration of version RELEASE @ line 155, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: junit:junit:jar -> duplicate declaration of version RELEASE @ line 160, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:jar -> duplicate declaration of version RELEASE @ line 184, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building com.messanger.chat 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.0.CR1 has been relocated to org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.0.CR1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ com.messanger.chat ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ com.messanger.chat ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 576 resources
[INFO] Copying 20 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ com.messanger.chat ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 20 source files to /Users/Chaklader/IdeaProjects/SpringChatApp/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/Chaklader/IdeaProjects/SpringChatApp/src/main/java/com/sergialmar/wschat/config/RedisConfig.java:[14,22] package redis.embedded does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Chaklader/IdeaProjects/SpringChatApp/src/main/java/com/sergialmar/wschat/config/RedisConfig.java:[35,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RedisServer
  location: class com.sergialmar.wschat.config.RedisConfig.RedisServerBean
[ERROR] /Users/Chaklader/IdeaProjects/SpringChatApp/src/main/java/com/sergialmar/wschat/config/RedisConfig.java:[40,43] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RedisServer
  location: class com.sergialmar.wschat.config.RedisConfig.RedisServerBean
[INFO] 3 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.042 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-04T19:29:34+06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 42M/792M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project com.messanger.chat: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/Chaklader/IdeaProjects/SpringChatApp/src/main/java/com/sergialmar/wschat/config/RedisConfig.java:[14,22] package redis.embedded does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Chaklader/IdeaProjects/SpringChatApp/src/main/java/com/sergialmar/wschat/config/RedisConfig.java:[35,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RedisServer
[ERROR]   location: class com.sergialmar.wschat.config.RedisConfig.RedisServerBean
[ERROR] /Users/Chaklader/IdeaProjects/SpringChatApp/src/main/java/com/sergialmar/wschat/config/RedisConfig.java:[40,43] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RedisServer
[ERROR]   location: class com.sergialmar.wschat.config.RedisConfig.RedisServerBean
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The `pom.xml` file is provided below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SpringChatApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.messanger.chat</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
            <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-messaging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor/reactor-net -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-net</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>    
</project>
```

Clearly, I have used the `embedded-redis` dependency in the project,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This is the file where I get the error message,

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;

import redis.clients.jedis.Protocol;
import redis.embedded.RedisServer;

/**
 * Redis is required for {@link EnableRedisHttpSession} handling.
 */
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public static RedisServerBean redisServer() {
        return new RedisServerBean();
    }

    /**
     * Implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor to ensure this Bean is
     * initialized before any other Beans. Specifically, we want to ensure that
     * the Redis Server is started before RedisHttpSessionConfiguration attempts
     * to enable Keyspace notifications.
     */
    static class RedisServerBean implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean, BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

        private RedisServer redisServer;

        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

            redisServer = new RedisServer(Protocol.DEFAULT_PORT);
            redisServer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() throws Exception {
            if (redisServer != null) {
                redisServer.stop();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        }

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        }

    }
}
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope you put for the dependency is test. So it is not included when using `clean install`. Remove the scope tag and try again.

For more information on maven dependency scopes:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: `BUILD SUCCESS`

Comment: Do you know how can I run `mvn compile:compile` ? I get the error `No plugin found for prefix 'compile' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories`

Comment: Assuming the plugin is included in your pom.xml, you have a typo. `compiler` not `compile`. Example: `mvn compiler:compile`.

Comment: I recommend you read a bit more in depth about maven build lifecycle. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

And a side note: (I think) compiler plugin already exists in maven by default, which is why the `mvn compiler:compile` command worked without it existing in the `pom.xml`. Apologize for misleading.